# Reference to equation of correlation of log-normal random variables

Tags: correlation, references, lognormal-distribution, cross-correlation

In another question here at Cross Validated, one user asked for the correlation of log-normal random variables.

Here's the link for the question: [Correlation of log-normal random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6853/correlation-of-log-normal-random-variables)

The accepted answer presents an equation for the correlation between log-normal random variables Y1 e Y2 as final answer.

[image]

I'd like to find/know if there's a reference for this equation, either in an article or in a book. I have been searching for it in books and articles in my field (Operational Hydrology) but I haven't been able to find it so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find it in Johnson and Kotz (1972) p20. [1]

an alternative reference (that refers to Johnson & Kotz) is Lai, Rayner & Hutchinson (1999) [2]

[1] Johnson, N. L. and Kotz, S. (1972).
*Distributions in Statistics: Continuous Multivariate Distributions.*
New York, Wiley.

[2] Lai, C.D., J.C.W. Rayner, and T.P. Hutchinson, (1999),
"Robustness of the sample correlation the bivariate lognormal case,"
*Journal of Applied Mathematics & Decision Sciences*, 3(1), 7-19