# How can we simulate the sensitivity of Pearson correlation coefficient to the distributions of variables?

Tags: correlation, normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution, pearson-r

I want to make a simulation experiment on the sensitivity of Pearson correlation coefficient to the distribution types of variables. In other words, I want to demonstrate "*when the distributions of variables are not Gaussian, the Pearson correlation coefficient of samples is expected to be not a good estimator of that for the population.*"

With support of Python, I firstly sampled 10000 examples from a bivariate normal distribution with a arbitrarily defined mean vector and covariance matrix, i.e., $\mu=[0; 0]$, $\Sigma=[1, 0.6; 0.6, 1]$. The two variables are termed here as $X_1$ and $X_2$. Then I constructed a multivariate log-normal distribution by performing '*exponential*' transformation on $X_1$ and $X_2$, i.e., $Y_1=e^{X_1}$, $Y_2=e^{X_2}$. After that, I calculated the Pearson correlation coefficient of $\rho(X_1$, $X_2)$, and $\rho(Y_1$,$Y_2)$.

If there is a large difference between $\rho(Y_1$,$Y_2)$ and $\rho(X_1$, $X_2)$, can I believe that my proposition is validated?

**My viewpoint**: I think this experiment is questionable, because we do not know the theoretical correlation for the log-normal variables $Y_1$ and $Y_2$, or the correlation of $X_1$ and $X_2$ is not equivalent to that for $Y_1$ and $Y_2$. However, how can we simulate two log-normal samples with a known correlation coefficient?

The following is my code and the result:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Simulate correlated variables x and y
rho = 0.6
mu = [0, 0]
C = [[1, rho], [rho, 1]]
N = 10000
X1, X2 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu, C, N).T

# test = np.corrcoef(X1, X2)
fig = plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2, 3, 1)
plt.hist(X1, bins = 30, density = True, edgecolor = 'k')
plt.xlabel(r'$X1$')
plt.subplot(2, 3, 2)
plt.hist(X2, bins = 30, density = True, edgecolor = 'k')
plt.xlabel(r'$X2$')
plt.subplot(2, 3, 3)
plt.scatter(X1, X2, marker = 'o', edgecolors = 'k')
plt.xlabel('X1')
plt.ylabel('X2')

# Construct the log-normal distributions
Y1 = np.exp(X1)
Y2 = np.exp(X2)

plt.subplot(2, 3, 4)
plt.hist(Y1, bins = 30, density = True, edgecolor = 'k')
plt.xlabel(r'$Y1=e^{X1}$')
plt.subplot(2, 3, 5)
plt.hist(Y2, bins = 30, density = True, edgecolor = 'k')
plt.xlabel(r'$Y2=e^{X2}$')
plt.subplot(2, 3, 6)
plt.scatter(Y1, Y2, marker = 'o', edgecolors = 'k')
plt.xlabel('Y1')
plt.ylabel('Y2')

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: The correllation of the lognormal in terms of the correlation of the normal (and other parameters) is given in posts here on site. One issue is that the relationship between the lognormals is not *linear*. Even if your normals are perfectly correlated, the lognormals won't be (except in special cases)

Comment: for a formula, see for example https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6853/correlation-of-log-normal-random-variables

Comment: There's another post here which (almost) does the correlation going the other direction (it gives the correlation of the normal in terms of the covariance of the lognormal).

Comment: Also relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41734/attainable-correlations-for-lognormal-random-variables

Comment: The statement you are trying to demonstrate is too broad and vague to admit of any demonstration.